# Can not build apk --release in flutter

Tags: flutter, compiler-errors

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.
>     Keystore file not set for signing config release
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 28s Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Running
>   Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                      29.5s
>   Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

Comment: storePassword=cit123456
keyPassword=cit123456
keyAlias=citkey
storeFile=D:/Flutter/key/citkey.jks

Comment: I would not post your store password or any other password